# Making POST request with AJAX returns a 400 error (without jQuery)

Tags: ajax, javascript

The website has a blog page with a search field and category checkboxes. Searching for something or checking/unchecking a category starts an AJAX request to get the posts based on the search/categories, then populates those results into the list on the page.

**Currently this functionality works with jQuery, but my attempts to write it in plain JS are failing with 400 errors.**

Here is the jQuery for this that works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Knuckle.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
        action: 'kp_filters',
        nonce: Knuckle.nonce,
        form: serialized_form,
        base_url: base_url
    },
    success: function( response ){
        // console.log('===== SUCCESS =====');
        // console.log(response);

        if( response.results && response.results.length ){
            $('.results-item').remove();
            $('.results-pagination').remove();

            for(i=0; i<response.results.length; i++){
                $('.results-list').append( response.results[i] );
            }

            if( response.pagination && response.pagination.length ){
                $('.results-inner').append( response.pagination );
            }

        } else {
            // No results.
            $('.results-item').remove();
            $('.results-pagination').remove();
        }

    },
    error: function( response ){
        // console.log('===== ERROR =====');
        // console.log(response);
    },
    complete: function( response ){
        // console.log('===== COMPLETE =====');
        // console.log(response);

        // Remove the loading indicator
        $('.sk-circle').removeClass('is-loading');

    }
});
```

Here's the plain Javascript version of the above snippet, which is getting the 400 errors:

```
var serialized_form = encodeURI( kp_serialize(window.mirrored_params) );
var base_url = kp_get_base_url();

var data = {
    url: Knuckle.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    action: 'kp_filters',
    nonce: Knuckle.nonce,
    form: serialized_form,
    base_url: base_url
};
console.log('About to post this data: ');
console.log(data);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', Knuckle.ajaxurl);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if( xhr.readyState === DONE ){
        console.log('ajax is done: ' + xhr.status);
        if( xhr.status === OK ){
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
    }
};

xhr.send(data);
```

Here's a screenshot of what I get in the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3F6u.jpg

I've been messing with the data and trying different headers for my XMLHttpRequest, but it always comes back with a 400. Tried disabling plugins that might have an effect on it, but nothing there either.

**What am I doing wrong with the plain JS AJAX? What is jQuery doing that my code isn't?**

Comment: Convert `data` to a `string`, i.e.: `data = 'action=kp_filters&nonce=' + Knuckle.nonce + '&form=' + serialized_form + '&base_url=' + base_url;`. And secondly, the request header should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! I serialized the data and added the different header and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sally CJ for helping me out! The problem was that the data needs to be sent as a serialized string (query string) and my request header was wrong.

Here is the final working function I have now. Sorry about the extraneous stuff about the loading animation and the scrolling to the top of the results list. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

```
function kp_submit_filters(){
// console.log( 'START kp_submit_filters()' );
// console.log( window.mirrored_params );

// Start the loading animation.
var loading_indicator = document.querySelectorAll('.sk-circle');
if( loading_indicator.length ){
    kpAddClass(loading_indicator, 'is-loading');
}

// Scroll to the top of the results.
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.results');
if (target.length) {
    var target_shape = target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var target_position = target_shape.top + window.pageYOffset;
    window.scroll({
        top: target_position - 60,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });

}


// Set up some data to send in the AJAX request.
var base_url = kp_get_base_url();

var data = window.mirrored_params;
    data.action = 'kp_filters';
    data.nonce = Knuckle.nonce;
    data.base_url = base_url;

// Serialize and encode the data object.
var serialized_data = encodeURI( kp_serialize(data) );

// console.log('About to post this data: ');
// console.log( data );
// console.log( serialized_data );

// Make the request object.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Set up what happens with the response - remove existing result items and pagination, add the new search result items and pagination to the DOM, and also stop the loading animation.

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if( xhr.readyState === DONE ){
        // console.log('ajax is done: ' + xhr.status);
        if( xhr.status === OK ){
            // console.log('status is OK');
            // console.log(xhr);
            // console.log(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'

            var response = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );
            var result_items = document.querySelectorAll('.results-item');
            var result_pagination = document.querySelectorAll('.results-pagination');
            var results_list = document.querySelectorAll('.results-list');

            if( response.results && response.results.length ){

                // Remove the existing items.
                for( i=0; i<result_items.length; i++){
                    result_items[i].parentNode.removeChild(result_items[i]);
                }

                // Remove the existing pagination.
                for( i=0; i<result_pagination.length; i++){
                    result_pagination[i].parentNode.removeChild(result_pagination[i]);
                }

                // Add the new items and pagination to the DOM.
                if( results_list.length ){
                    for(i=0; i<response.results.length; i++){
                        results_list[0].innerHTML += response.results[i];
                    }

                    if( response.pagination && response.pagination.length ){
                        results_list[0].innerHTML += response.pagination;
                    }

                }



            } else {
                // No results, so just remove the existing items and pagination.

                for( i=0; i<result_items.length; i++){
                    result_items[i].parentNode.removeChild(result_items[i]);
                }

                for( i=0; i<result_pagination.length; i++){
                    result_pagination[i].parentNode.removeChild(result_pagination[i]);
                }

            }

        }

        // Hide the loading animation.
        if( loading_indicator.length ){
            kpRemoveClass(loading_indicator, 'is-loading');
        }

    } else {
        // console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
    }

};

// Send the POST request via AJAX.
xhr.open('POST', Knuckle.ajaxurl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send( serialized_data );

return false;
}
```